# Как получить параметры из route path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, route, react-router

Столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно получить параметр, который был передан в route.
Есть код:

```
<Route exact path="/id:id" component={UserPage} />
```

Нужно в UserPage получать параметр id, каким это образом можно сделать?

Нужно, чтобы по адресу {имя сайта}/id{номер страницы} рендерился `UserPage`

### UPD

Версия реакт-роута - 4.1.2

Comment: версия роутера то какая? его четыре раза переписывали

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: this.props.match.params.id

Comment: угу, так и решил, думал записать ответ, но все уже работает и ладно

Answer (score 0):

В 4 версии роутера, насколько я помню, вот так:

```
<Route exact path="/id:id" render={ () => <UserPage id={someId}/> } />
```

Comment: простите UPD не увидел